# How to find difference between the integers ignoring null values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Data looks like this

```
Row CurrentPrice    PriceChangeDate  PreviousPrice
1   7.9              25/03/2022      null
2   null             25/03/2022      null
3   7.9              24/03/2022      null
4   8                01/03/2022      8.5
5   8.5              24/02/2022      8
```

Expected Output

```
Row CurrentPrice    PriceChangeDate  PreviousPrice  Difference
1   7.9             25/03/2022       7.9            0
2   7.9             24/03/2022       8              0.1
3   8               01/03/2022       8.5            0.5
4   8.5             24/02/2022       8              -0.5
```

I am not able to find a way to get the expected data.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *, round(PreviousPrice - CurrentPrice, 2) as Difference
from (
  select * except(PreviousPrice), 
    ifnull(PreviousPrice, lag(CurrentPrice) over(order by PriceChangeDate)) as PreviousPrice
  from your_table
  where not CurrentPrice is null
)
```

if applied to sample data in y our question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, you can use [IFNULL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#ifnull) conditional expressions to ignore the null values. You can try the code below where you can [SAFE_CAST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#safe_casting) the values to float inside IFNULL conditional expressions.

```
 SELECT * EXCEPT(PreviousPrice),
 ifnull(SAFE_CAST(PreviousPrice AS FLOAT64),0) AS PreviousPrice,
 ROUND(ifnull(SAFE_CAST(PreviousPrice AS FLOAT64),0) - ifnull(SAFE_CAST(CurrentPrice AS FLOAT64),0),2) AS Difference
 FROM (
 SELECT * EXCEPT(ROW,PreviousPrice),
   ifnull(PreviousPrice,
   LAG(CurrentPrice) OVER(ORDER BY PriceChangeDate)) AS PreviousPrice
 FROM `project.dataset.pricechange`
 WHERE NOT CurrentPrice = 'null'
 ORDER BY PriceChangeDate DESC )
```

**Output Table**

[image]